# Servlet URL pattern match with slash prefix

Tags: java, servlets

I have the servlet annotation as:

```
@WebServlet (name="PageServlet", urlPatterns={"*.zt"})
```

`zt` is the file extension I am using.

However if I use

```
@WebServlet (name="PageServlet", urlPatterns={"/*.zt"})
```

It does not match the URL such as `/app/index.zt` , nor `/app/foo/test.zt`... How can I match only the `zt` files under root `/app/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servlet container either uses path mapping or extension mapping. You cannot use a combination of the two. See ¶12.2 of the Servlet Specification:

> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<context- root>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `*` is not treated as `wild-card`, you have to use `/app/*`

Example 1 : /string1/*/string2 , `*`  will work as wild-card

> @WebServlet(
>     urlPatterns={"/string1/*/string2"} ,
>     name="ServletName",
>   initParams={ 
>        @WebInitParam(name = "name", value = "string2")
>   } )

Example 2 :

> @WebServlet(
>   urlPatterns={"/string1/*"} ,
>   name="ServletName"
>   )